# Writing proofs of simple arithmetic in Coq

Tags: coq, integer-arithmetic

I would like to prove simple things like for every natural number n, there exists a natural number k such that:

```
(2*n + 1)^2 = 8*k + 1
```

How does one go about such a proof? I thought of dividing it into cases when n is odd or even, but I do not know how to do so in Coq. Also, is there an inbuilt power (exponent) operator in Coq?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are many built-in functions, you just need the right set of imports or open the right notation scope.
One easy way to do the proof is to use induction and some automation like [`ring`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactics.html#hevea_tactic200),  [`omega`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactics.html#hevea_tactic199) or [`lia`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/micromega.html#hevea_tactic279) tactics.

```
From Coq Require Import Arith Psatz.

Goal forall n, exists k, (2*n + 1)^2 = 8*k + 1.
Proof.
  induction n as [| n [m IH]].
  - now exists 0.
  - exists (S n + m). rewrite Nat.pow_2_r in *. lia.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can follow the initial plan suggested in the question of reasoning by cases on whether the input is odd or even, only representing parity by the value of `n mod 2` and using a boolean equality test to express the alternative.

The proof can also be made with relative integers instead of natural numbers.

```
From Coq Require Import ZArith Psatz.

Open Scope Z_scope.

Lemma example n : exists k,  (2 * n + 1) ^2 = 8 * k + 1.
Proof.
assert (vn : n = 2 * (n / 2) + n mod 2) by now apply Z_div_mod_eq.
destruct (n mod 2 =? 0) eqn: q.
-  rewrite Z.eqb_eq in q; rewrite vn, q.
exists ((2 * (n / 2) + 1) * (n / 2)); ring.
-  enough (vm : n mod 2 = 1)
    by now rewrite vn, vm; exists (2 * (n / 2) ^ 2 + 3 * (n / 2) + 1); ring.
rewrite Z.eqb_neq in q.
assert (0 <= n mod 2 < 2) by now apply Z_mod_lt.
lia.
Qed.
```

This proof is not as nice and elementary as the one by @Anton on Jan 24th, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative proof, using the same idea as found in the proof by @Yves:

```
From Coq Require Import Arith Psatz.

Fact exampleNat n : exists k, (2 * n + 1) ^2 = 8 * k + 1.
Proof.
  exists (n * (S n) / 2).
  assert (H : Nat.even (n * (S n)) = true) by
    now rewrite Nat.even_mul, Nat.even_succ, Nat.orb_even_odd.
  apply Nat.even_spec in H as [m H]; rewrite (Nat.mul_comm 2) in H.
  rewrite H, Nat.div_mul, Nat.pow_2_r; lia.
Qed.
```

Observe that this proof schema works for the integer numbers too provided you change everything from namespace `Nat` to `Z` (`S` to `Z.succ`, etc.).